# Vector space generated

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $(L,+)<(\mathbb R^n,+)$ be a additive subgroup and let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ be a maximal linearly independent subset of $L$. Let $V$ be the subspace spanned by $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$. Asumme that $m<n$.

How I can prove that  $\dim_\mathbb R \left<L\right><n$?

Thank you all.

Comment: Does the "$<$" in the first sentence indicate the proper subspace relation?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected.

Comment: if you say that you need an additive subgroup then it is not obvious that you will have a vector subspace in general.

Comment: Were you unable to make headway with my hint? If so, let me know what is causing you trouble, and I'll see what I can do to get you unstuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea, here, is to show that $\langle L\rangle=\langle v_1,...,v_m\rangle,$ so that $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is a basis for $\langle L\rangle,$ and so $\dim_{\Bbb R}\langle L\rangle=m<n.$

Since $v_1,...,v_m\in L,$, then clearly $\langle v_1,...,v_m\rangle\subseteq \langle L\rangle.$ On the other hand, if $v\in L,$ then since $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is a maximal linearly independent subset of $L,$ what can you conclude about $\{v_1,...,v_m,v\}$? What does this tell you about $v$ and $\langle v_1,...,v_m\rangle$? What does this tell you about $L$ and $\langle v_1,...,v_m\rangle$? What does this tell you about $\langle L\rangle$ and $\langle v_1,...,v_m\rangle$?

**Added**: It's worth noting that there's nothing special about $L$ being an additive subgroup of $\Bbb R^n.$ Let's take an arbitrary vector space $V$ over an arbitrary field $\Bbb F,$ an arbitrary subset $A$ of $V,$ and an arbitrary maximal linearly independent subset $B$ of $A.$ Then we can show that $\langle B\rangle=\langle A\rangle.$ Hence, if there exist finite $m,n$ such that $\dim_{\Bbb F}V=n$ and $B$ has $m$ elements, then $\dim_{\Bbb F}\langle A\rangle=m<n.$

We proceed by noting that for any subset $C$ of $V,$ $\langle C\rangle$ is defined to be the intersection of all subspaces $W$ of $V$ such that $C\subseteq W.$ Since $B\subseteq A,$ then readily, $\langle B\rangle\subseteq\langle A\rangle.$ Now, since $B$ is a maximal linearly independent subset of $A,$ then for any $x\in A\setminus B,$ we have that $B\cup\{x\}$ is *not* linearly independent. From this, we can show (recalling that $B$ is linearly independent) that $v\in\langle B.$ Hence, $A\setminus B\subseteq\langle B\rangle,$ and of course $B\subseteq\langle B\rangle,$ so $A\subseteq\langle B\rangle.$ Thus, $\langle B\rangle$ is a subspace of $V$ containing $A,$ so by definition of $A,$ we have $\langle A\rangle\subseteq\langle B\rangle.$ By double-inclusion, we have (as desired) that $\langle B\rangle=\langle A\rangle.$

Comment: -----thank you, Cameron Buie----

Comment: You're very welcome.